# async/await node v9 "unexpected token function" when defining async function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, async-await

i want to use async/await in my app, basically for querying my db

i have this function :

```
async function getVariables() {

    var id = await Service.getIdByName('JollyClick')

    console.log(id)

}
```

which is supposed to call this :

```
serviceSchema.statics.getIdByName = async function getIdByName (serviceName) {

    this.findOne({name :serviceName }).exec().then(function(service){
        return service._id
    })
}
```

but i get an error :

```
async function getVariables() {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

i am using node v9

please help !

Comment: Is the error happening when you run the script, or just in the IDE?

Comment: i havent run it anywhere else than outside the c9 IDE where i sat up a node js environment

Comment: Have you tried running on the command line, e.g. node myscript.js and see what you get?

Comment: Any version of Node > 7.6 should have no problem with the async keyword, that's why I suspect it's something in the C9 setup that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the async on the getIdByName function, eg

```
serviceSchema.statics.getIdByName = function getIdByName (serviceName) {

    this.findOne({name :serviceName }).exec().then(function(service){
        return service._id
    })
}
```

would be fine.

I don't think this is the source of your error though. Your code looks ok otherwise, it runs for me on Node 8.9.4, could your IDE be doing something annoying? I've seen WebStorm do this when you have not selected the correct JavaScript version.

Of course when you use await to call a function you are normally doing so with a function that returns a promise.

So I'd also change getIdByName like so:

```
serviceSchema.statics.getIdByName = function getIdByName (serviceName) {

    return this.findOne({name :serviceName }).exec().then(function(service){
       return service._id;
    })
}
```

This keeps the promise chain intact.

The syntax:

async function getVariables() {

Is correct in any case.

If your IDE is targeting an older version of JavaScript it might not allow you to use the async keyword.

Try this fiddle out to see the async keyword in use:

https://jsfiddle.net/u453mdkb/3/

Comment: my bad, deleted previous message, running it through terminal works! thanks
im new at this, what direction should i go to fix this?

Comment: `return Promise.resolve(service._id);` is not necessary.  You can just do `return service._id`.  A value returned from a `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of the promise chain.

Comment: Hey @mtts, I guess since it's a C9 issue, it's worth checking settings there. What version of JavaScript is being targeted etc. I'd be very surprised if you couldn't target recent versions of Node.